# Chrome and Firefox browsers are not opening while running my test cases from command prompt through ANT

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have written 3 test cases

**1  open the Google site in Firefox browser and search**

**2 open the Google site in  Chrome browser and search**

**3 Printing some messages,no browser involved**

From Eclipse I can run the above test cases properly

if i run testng.xml as testNG site From Eclipse then also all the above test cases running properly

but When ever i am trying to run my webdriver test cases from command prompt through ANT using build.xml

For the chrome browser  it showing alert related to manifest version and for  Firefox browser its showing error related to Unable to bind to locking port 7054 and my first two test cases getting failed. [ i have attached the fail report of those test cases ]

Can any one  give some suggestion what changes are required so that i can run my test cases properly from ant

**I am using selenium Webdriver java build [ latest one]**

**Framework : TestNg**

**Editor : Eclipse**

**Firefox browser version : 22.0**

**Chrome Browser version : 28.0.1500.72 m**

**OS: Windows 7 Ultimate**

I have attached the screenshot  related to

1 **chrome browser alert**

[image]

2 **chrome browser which opened but not able to open the site**

[image]

3 **Fail report of the test case which involved firefox driver**

[image]

4 **Fail report of the test case which involved chrome driver.**

[image]

5 **Screenshot of my project setup**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checking your system path for a path to chrome and FF might help . That worked for me though I didn't have a similar error.

Comment: Are you talking about  setting in Environment variable  system path ? 
chrome means  chrome driver or chrome browser?

Comment: Environment variables for the browser that goes to the directory where chrome.exe is located

Comment: in my environment variable  , firefox and chrome browser path are not present, though my chromedriver path is there in the environment variable.

where i will add chrome browser and firefox browser path? will i create another new variable or append in the path  variable

Comment: Just try appending in the Path variable

Comment: i am  usinfg testng-xslt report format , do u think i have to change something in it? i am getting no clue regarding this error, because it working fine when i am running from eclipse then why it is failing from ant.